# JIra container cannot find postgresql when run with mvn-docker plugin

Tags: postgresql, maven, docker, docker-compose, jira

We are developing a jira plugin. For integration tests I want to run the plugin in a dockerized container with postgresql as my db (standard integration tests from atlassian-sdk are no option because of testdata). When running both containers with docker-compose everything works as expected.

When I use the mvn-docker plugin, both containers are fired up, and the jira container can connect to the postgres container. The jira startup stops during the startup checks and freezes (The container is reachable and shows some message about database problems on the jira http address.

The postgresql container gives following log message: 
FATAL:  database "jiradb'" does not exist

Logging into the postgres container and a running psql -U jira -d jiradb succeeds, so the database is existing.

Used docker images are:

- postgres:9.5-alpine
- ownjira, it is based upon teamatldocker/jira and only copies our plugin into the jira, otherwise it is the teamatldocker/jira image (see Dockerfile below)

Docker-maven plugin section from pom.xml (database is not found):

```xml
 <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${docker.maven.plugin.fabric8.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <autoCreateCustomNetworks>true</autoCreateCustomNetworks>
          <logDate>default</logDate>
          <autoPull>true</autoPull>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <images>
            <image>
              <alias>postgresql</alias>
              <name>postgres:9.5-alpine</name>
              <run>
                <network>
                  <mode>custom</mode>
                  <name>test-network</name>
                  <alias>postgresql</alias>
                  <alias>db-alternative</alias>
                </network>
                <env>
                  <POSTGRES_USER>jira</POSTGRES_USER>
                  <POSTGRES_PASSWORD>jellyfish</POSTGRES_PASSWORD>
                  <POSTGRES_DB>jiradb</POSTGRES_DB>
                  <POSTGRES_ENCODING>UNICODE</POSTGRES_ENCODING>
                  <POSTGRES_COLLATE>C</POSTGRES_COLLATE>
                  <POSTGRES_COLLATE_TYPE>C</POSTGRES_COLLATE_TYPE>
                </env>
                <volumes>
                  <bind>
                    <volume>./postgresqldata/:/var/lib/postgresql/data</volume>
                  </bind>
                </volumes>

                <wait>
                  <log>database system is ready to accept connections</log>
                  <time>200000</time>
                </wait>
                <log>
                  <prefix>DB</prefix>
                  <color>yellow</color>
                </log>
              </run>
            </image>

            <image>
              <alias>jira</alias>
              <!-- <name>teamatldocker/jira</name> -->
              <!-- ownjira is teamatldocker/jira only with a copy of our plugin-->
              <name>ownjira</name>
              <run>
                <network>
                  <mode>custom</mode>
                  <name>test-network</name>
                  <alias>jira</alias>
                </network>
                <env>
                  <JIRA_DATABASE_URL>postgresql://jira@postgresql/jiradb'</JIRA_DATABASE_URL>
                  <JIRA_DB_PASSWORD>jellyfish</JIRA_DB_PASSWORD>
                  <SETENV_JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY>2048m</SETENV_JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY>
                  <SETENV_JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY>4096m</SETENV_JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY>
                  <DOCKER_WAIT_HOST>postgresql</DOCKER_WAIT_HOST>
                  <DOCKER_WAIT_PORT>5432</DOCKER_WAIT_PORT>
                  <JIRA_PROXY_NAME></JIRA_PROXY_NAME>
                  <JIRA_PROXY_PORT></JIRA_PROXY_PORT>
                  <JIRA_PROXY_SCHEME></JIRA_PROXY_SCHEME>
                </env>
                <volumes>
                  <bind>
                    <volume>./jiradata/:/var/atlassian/jira</volume>
                  </bind>
                </volumes>
                <ports>
                  <port>80:8080</port>
                  <port>2990:2990</port>
                </ports>
                <wait>
                  <log>Plugins upgrades completed successfully</log>
                  <time>3000000</time>
                </wait>
                <log>
                  <prefix>JIRA</prefix>
                  <color>cyan</color>
                </log>
              </run>
            </image>
          </images>
        </configuration>

        <!-- Hooking into the lifecycle -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

docker-compose (everything works fine):

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  jira:
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    # image: teamatldocker/jira
    image: ownjira
    networks:
      - jiranet
    volumes:
      - ./jiradata/:/var/atlassian/jira
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '2990:2990'
    environment:
      - 'JIRA_DATABASE_URL=postgresql://jira@postgresql/jiradb'
      - 'JIRA_DB_PASSWORD=jellyfish'
      - 'SETENV_JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY=2048m'
      - 'SETENV_JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY=4096m'
      - 'DOCKER_WAIT_HOST=postgresql'
      - 'DOCKER_WAIT_PORT=5432'
      - 'JIRA_PROXY_NAME='
      - 'JIRA_PROXY_PORT='
      - 'JIRA_PROXY_SCHEME='
    logging:
      # limit logs retained on host to 25MB
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "50"

  postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine
    networks:
      - jiranet
    volumes:
      - ./postgresqldata/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=jira'
      # CHANGE THE PASSWORD!
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=jellyfish'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=jiradb'
      - 'POSTGRES_ENCODING=UNICODE'
      - 'POSTGRES_COLLATE=C'
      - 'POSTGRES_COLLATE_TYPE=C'
    logging:
      # limit logs retained on host to 25MB
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "50"

volumes:
  setupdata:
    external: false
  jiradata:
    external: false
  postgresqldata:
    external: false



networks:
  jiranet:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile for ownjira image:

```
FROM teamatldocker/jira

USER root

COPY *.obr /var/atlassian/jira/plugins/installed-plugins/

USER jira
CMD ["jira"]
```

Any I think the problem is either in the JIRA_DATABASE_URL of the mvn-docker plugin or in the network setup. But I tried a lot of different combinations there, and if I change the host I get a host not reachable, so I guess the network is working correctly.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Update: Additional Information: Same problem occurs with mysql instead of Postgresql or with other Postgresql versions.